# CSV data to Python dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, dictionary

I wrote my data which was in lists and dicts to a csv file, and when i import the csv file using `pd.read_csv('file.csv')`, everything becomes strings. How can i keep or convert it to its original format?

Originally, everything was in a dataframe and then written to a CSV file using `df.to_csv(r'./file.csv')`.

```
csv_data['ln2']
Out[36]: 
0        {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
1        {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
2        {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
3        {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
4        {0: [67, 1], 1: [67, 1], 2: [67, 1], 3: [67, 1...
                               ...                        
43244    {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
43245    {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
43246    {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
43247    {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
43248    {0: [71, 1], 1: [73, 1], 2: [79, 1], 3: [80, 1...
Name: ln2, Length: 43249, dtype: object
```

all the rows are strings.

Comment: Save it to json, rather than csv.

Comment: *I wrote my data which was in lists and dicts to a csv file*. The problem lies probably there. If the data was in lists and dicts it is probably better to directly build a dataframe from that, unless you really know how to use the `csv` module. Anyway that is the part of code that you should show.

Comment: "I wrote my data which was in lists and dicts to a csv file" That is generally not a reasonable approach to serialization. You should use `pickle` or JSON if possible. Indeed, I would say, using a pandas dataframe for this sort of thing is an anti-pattern. pandas is not really designed around using Python objects as elements of the pandas containers (except for strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the column as dicts:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', converters={'ln2': eval})
```

Comment: This worked as well as the changing it to json. If i want to convert 2 columns this way, can i do it `...converters={['ln1', 'ln2': eval})` ?

Also, with json, everything imported nicely but now all dict keys have quotes, how do i prevent that?

Comment: @AnthonySirico Unfortunately, JSON requires string keys.

Comment: Yes, so for that purpose you could stick to using csv and load it as I indicated. Furthermore, `converters` requires a dict so it would be `{'ln1': eval, 'ln2': eval}`.